# How to get the Agent Email Address from amazon connect logged in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

i have build sample amazon connect login to get the agent details from javascript api, but do not have any docs to get agent email address i followed docs 
https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-streams/blob/master/Documentation.md
Kindly help me how to get the email adddress

Answer (score 2):

You can get the email address of the User by using the describeUser.

```
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var connect = new AWS.Connect();

    exports.handler = function (event) {
        var params = {
          InstanceId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
          UserId: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
        };
        connect.describeUser(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
            else console.log(data.User.IdentityInfo.Email);
        });
    }
```

From the documentation you posted:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Connect.html#describeUser-property

An example of what the User object looks like:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeUser.html